# Android NDK linker Error:error: undefined reference to std::basic_string

Tags: c++11, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, ndk-build

I am currently trying to build a static library of some source c++ files requiring boost. I have been following the [hello-libs](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs) example and have successfully linked the boost static file dependencies as is done in the sample example.Now said that, during while building the module I get these erros :

> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator const&)'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::string const&)'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string, std::allocator >::~basic_string()'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator const&)'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::string const&)'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator const&)'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(std::string const&)'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator const&)'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(std::string const&)'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator const&)'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator const&)'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(std::string const&)'
>
> Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator const&)'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator const&)'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator const&)'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator const&)'
>
> Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance(bool, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)'
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':dummy:linkDummyArmeabiDebugSharedLibrary'.
>
> A build operation failed.
>         Linker failed while linking libdummy.so.
>     See the complete log at: file:///home/cran-cg/Downloads/Hello-libs-boost/name/build/tmp/linkDummyArmeabiDebugSharedLibrary/output.txt

I had been trying to resolve this and had come upon many solutions on stackoverflow itself, suggesting that I should amend my linker path and include libc++.so library

```
ndk{
        moduleName = 'p2psp'
        stl = "c++_shared"
       // ldLibs.addAll('-L'+ file("/home/cran-cg/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi").absolutePath)
        ldLibs.addAll(['android', 'log','atomic'])/*"${NDK_ROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi",'gnustl_static'*/
        toolchain = "clang"
        cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
        cppFlags.add('-frtti')
        cppFlags.add('-fexceptions')
        cppFlags.addAll('-I' + file("/home/cran-cg/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include").absolutePath ,'-DANDROID', ' -DANDROID_NDK', '-DAWS_CUSTOM_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT', '-fPIC', '-fexceptions')
        //cppFlags.add("-I${lib_distribution_root}/boost/include".toString())
        //cppFlags.add("-I${file("src/main/jni/inc")}".toString())

        abiFilters.addAll(['armeabi'])//, 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'])
    }
```

And I am confused of what should be done. Please suggest me ways as to how can I resolve this issue. Thanks :))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your boost libraries were built against gnustl (or maybe stlport), whereas you're using libc++. You can't mix and match STLs as they are not ABI compatible.

If you replace `stl = "c++_shared"` with `stl = "gnustl_shared"`(or maybe `stlport_shared` then it should link. Alternatively build boost against `c++_shared`.

Comment: Yups that was the problem. resolved it :))
But with gnustl_shared i was getting the undefined reference to "to_chars". At last I had to comment out all the trace messages and it worked.

Comment: Hi @cRAN I'm running into a similar problem with undefined references to `to_chars`; could you elaborate on what you mean by "comment out all the trace messages"? Thanks!

Comment: ```TRACE("Waiting for the player at (" << endpoint.address().to_string() << ","
                                      << std::to_string(endpoint.port())
                                      << ")");``` 
something like this