# 'ndk112' added in .so symbols when built on Android studio

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, android-source, ndk-build

I am building an Android application using `Android.mk` file. I will call this application as A1.

I am given a third party native library in the form of `.so` file that has Utility functions. I will call this library as N1. N1 is built on Android studio by the third party vendor.

When I include N1 in A1 and try to build A1 using `Android.mk`, the compilation fails due to symbol mismatch error.

When I checked about the symbol mismatch, here is the difference:

a. Sample Symbol generated by Android Studio:
`_ZNSt6__ndk112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initEPKcm`

b. Same symbol generated by `Android.mk` using the header files of N1 that is present in A1:
`_ZNSt6__basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initEPKcm`

The difference is, N1 has '`ndk112`' added in each of its symbol. This can be seen if we open the `.so` file in Notepad++.

I searched a lot to check of there are any flags that can be used to fix this issue, but couldn't get any reference. Can someone help me in removing '`ndk112`' from the symbols of a `.so` file generated using Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Same cause as https://stackoverflow.com/a/38798556/632035. N1 and A1 are using different STLs. They must use the same STL. You need to have A1 rebuilt with libc++.

Comment: I believe, in this case it is the A1 that must be rebuilt with APP_STL=c++_shared. **ndk1::** namespace is what you would expect in with libc++, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47051702/192373

Comment: Yep, had them backwards. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I quite didn't get how do I proceed. As @AlexCohn said, I observe that libc++.so linked to N1.so built on AOSP and libc++_shared.so linked to N1.so built on Android Studio. The build.gradle of N1 contains
        `externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11"
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
            }
        }`
Now I do not know the equivalent change that I have to make in Android.mk so as to achieve the correct linking.

Comment: You should not use AOSP build for **N1** unless your goal is a system preinstalled app. As for **A1**: make sure you use latest NDK release; add `APP_STL=c++_shared` either in **Application.mk** file near your **Android.mk** or on `ndk-build` command line.